# how to prevent imagecreatefrom from creating a static gif - PHP

Tags: php, image, gif

I have a script that sends an image it is saved as a .gif as declared in the movie.php file that will be listed below.
However, as I understand it, it creates an image from the gif making it useless for display because it simply becomes a static image .gif.
Anyway
I wanted to know how I can upload this file and ignore this function (imagecreatefromgif) I tried to change it in several ways and when I remove it I get an error, someone could help me work around this so that the gif will be sent and not be converted to a gif file static. basically I wanted that the way I sent the gif it would only be renamed with function imageGenerateName () but that it would keep all its size and property.
Every help is welcome.
Thanks in advance
.
Movie.php code:

```
<?php

  class Movie {

    public function imageGenerateName() {
      return bin2hex(random_bytes(60)) . ".gif";
    }

  }
```

movie-process.php code

```
<?php
          // Upload  img
          if(isset($_FILES["image"]) && !empty($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"])) {
    
            $image = $_FILES["image"];
            $imageTypes = ["image/gif"];
            $jpgArray = ["image/gif"];
    
            // Check img type
            if(in_array($image["type"], $imageTypes)) {
    
              // Check img type
              if(in_array($image["type"], $jpgArray)) {
                $imageFile = imagecreatefromgif($image["tmp_name"]);
              } else {
                $imageFile = imagecreatefromgif($image["tmp_name"]);
              }   
              // image name
              $imageName = $movie->imageGenerateName();
    
              imagegif($imageFile, "./img/movies/" . $imageName, 100);
    
              $movie->image = $imageName;
    
            } 
          }  
              // Upload img
              if(isset($_FILES["image"]) && !empty($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"])) {
    
                $image = $_FILES["image"];
                $imageTypes = ["image/gif"];
                $jpgArray = ["image/gif"];
    
                // Check img type
                if(in_array($image["type"], $imageTypes)) {
    
                  // check type is gif
                  if(in_array($image["type"], $jpgArray)) {
                    $imageFile = imagecreatefromgif($image["tmp_name"]);
                  }
    
                  // generete img name
                  $movie = new Movie();
    
                  $imageName = $movie->imageGenerateName();
    
                  imagegif($imageFile, "./img/movies/" . $imageName, 100);
    
                  $movieData->image = $imageName;   
                }
            }
```

Comment: I'm always worried when I see exactly the same code in the `then`-clause of an `if` statement as I see in the `else`-clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `imagecreatefromgif` function will only read the first image of the gif as the PHP [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromgif.php) says.

I tried before to solve this, but there is no turnaround other than uploading the image without touching it. PHP uses the [GD library](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) and this library doesn't have the proper functionality to deal with gif images other than just saving the image with the *.gif extension.

So, this is my suggested solution:

```
// generete img name
$movie = new Movie();
$imageName = $movie->imageGenerateName();
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"./img/movies/" . $imageName);
$movieData->image = $imageName;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think since you say you just want to save it as it is, with the same size and its all properties, you can use below code

```
<?php

    $allowed = array('gif');
    $filename = $_FILES["image"]['name'];
    $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if (in_array($ext, $allowed)) {
    
                    // generete img name
                    $movie = new Movie();
                    $imageName = $movie->imageGenerateName();

          $uploadResult = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], dirname( dirname( __FILE__ ) ).'/img/movies/'. $imageName );
                    
            if($uploadResult === true ){
                    $movie->image = $imageName;    
            }else{
                throw new \Exception('Unable to copy file to the given path');
            }
    }
```

Or if you have access to the Imagick lib php extension refer to below link on how to install this php-extension

https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setup.php

then using the functions in that library you can do

```
<?php 

        $allowed = array('gif');
        $filename = $_FILES["image"]['name'];
        $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if (in_array($ext, $allowed)) {

$image = new Imagick(); 
$image->readImage($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);

$image = $image->coalesceImages(); 

foreach ($image as $frame) { 
  $frame->cropImage($crop_w, $crop_h, $crop_x, $crop_y); 
  $frame->thumbnailImage($size_w, $size_h); 
  $frame->setImagePage($size_w, $size_h, 0, 0); 
} 

$image = $image->deconstructImages(); 
$image->writeImages(dirname( dirname( __FILE__ ) ).'/img/movies/'. $imageName, true); 

}
?>
```